# Magento 2.1.1 import products only

Tags: magento-2.1, product, import

suddenly all products disappeared from the magento catalog.
I have a backup of the database on a daily basis.
How can I import only catalog/category data from the dump or just import everything without order / invoice data?

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 0):

From the database dump its difficult to import only categories.Simple is that just go ahead and replace database with latest dump you have.

Note: You need to take backup whenever you are going to change or modify the files/database.